# in XCOM how do I fire or choose another soldier

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I just got myself the new XCOM, started the singleplayer campagin and went through the first mission, got back to HQ and made some choices and then comes the second mission.

Player is directed to place one of its soldiers inside the door, then its veteran atop the roof and then it is are free to place the last two as it see fit, the enemies turn and they fire at it's guy on the roof but miss.

Players turn, I select the guy on the roof, enter tactical mode and select an alien to fire at but nothing happens. Selecting OK doesn't work, pressing with the mouse doesn't. I am not allowed to throw a grenade ort fire a rocket or even select another soldier or move this one. Stuck in tcatical mode but can't do anything.

First time it happened I wondered if it was a bugg or if I missed something in the tutorial of the first battle but restarting, playing through again and same thing happens again..

Even been through the stage when I pressed every thing on the screen and then everything on the keyboard to get somewhere but no luck.

...frustrated but gratefull for assistance.

Comment: hit tab to select another soldier

Comment: There are some bugs in tactical mode where it just hangs and you have to quit/reload an earlier save. The latest update on Steam is supposed to fix some/all of them, though.

Comment: Not an answer, but I have the exact same issue on the exact same mission. Can switch between aliens targeted using the tab key. Selecting a fire mode and target is all I can do; nothing else is possible. Hitting the ok (or whatever it's called) does nothing, backspace for end of turn is a no go, and even hitting esc does NOTHING. I've got to ctr-alt-del, start task manager, to even shut down the game.

Answer (score 5):

You are still in tutorial mode, are forced to shoot on the other alien, just hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to change to second alien, and then you'll be free to shoot it, and continue the mission as you see fit.

Take notice that later in that mission you will be encouraged to use the rocket launcher to kill some aliens that appear later, however, this time it's not mandatory and you can kill them in whatever way you see fit.